# Api to fetch Facebook Ads Spent

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to Fetch the total amount spent on adds on all pages
I am using this api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/insights?fields=spend&level=account&date_preset=yesterday&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

but it gives this error

```
    {
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request.",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "H+JQTVfd95J"
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely reasons for that are that you're using the wrong token (one with the wrong scopes or one which hasn't got access to the account ID you specified), or you specified the wrong account ID

Comment: this works now, But still has issues.

I have created app in one facebook account that has business account too, And when i authenticated that account with app its working

But this is not working for others, i.e if other people login with app, it redirect with token.. and when i use that token it says

{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 3,
        "fbtrace_id": "AFQdSrydr7I"
    }
}

Comment: And you're sure your app is approved by Facebook for users to grant you the permissions necessary to access those parts of the API? If it's not approved, you'll likely only be able to use access tokens from admins of the app except for the most basic API calls

Comment: App is live, It says "Your app is currently live and available to the public"

Comment: You can see here,
https://s.nimbusweb.me/share/1767416/r45kcddsl3i4szzk6ryz

Comment: Its the issue with non admins
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 3,
        "fbtrace_id": "DPB9QTb+1PU"
    }
}